# Reset time part of Calendar instance in Java

Tags: java, date, time, format, reset

There is Java code,which is ran on 2 different environments and inserts records with `JdbcTemplate` to **DB**.

Results of its running are different for both envs. Particularly,for `Date` fields.

On first environment(Oracle XE) it produces record:

```
"12/03/2010";191094;"71697211000";3229;880323202;NULL;0;1;0;NULL;0;NULL
```

Second environment(Oracle non XE):

```
"12/03/2010 12:00:00";191094;"71697211000";3229;880323202;NULL;0;1;0;NULL;0;NULL
```

***NLS_DATE_FORMAT***(if it's crucial) for first env is `DD-MON-RR`,
for second env is `DD-MON-RRRR`

The question is,what Oracle settings may affect,that second env Date format is another?

Comment: Just don't store/retrieve the time part in DB. Use a `DATE` field type, not `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: I use Date type field in DB. Seems, that i have misunderstadings with customer. He said,that 12:00 should not be included.But it's not displayed with just select.it's displayed,when i use SELECT to_char(a_date, 'DD-mm-yy HH:MI:SS')

Answer (score 30, accepted):

should set following Calendar properties in Java code:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

instead of:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: Is there situation when it can return not 0 ?

Comment: @user12384512 `getActualMinimum` can return values other than `0`, but not for the listed above fields.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_char_sql.htm), `HH` refers to a 12-hour time.  The 12 in the time you're retrieving is 12 midnight.  What you want is `HH24`, which ges you a 24-hour time, starting at 00 for midnight.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to show the time part, don't include a format string which *includes* the time part ("HH:MI:SS").

You've reset the time part to midnight, basically... there's no way of differentiating between a `Calendar` or `Date` set to exactly midnight and a `Calendar` or `Date` "without" a time part - because there's no such concept as a `Calendar`/`Date` with only a date part.

Now you may be able to have that in the database, depending on what types are available to you - but `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` always represent points in time, not just dates.

The reason it's showing 12 instead of 00 is because you're using "HH" instead of "HH24", as per lacqui's answer. I assume you don't really *want* to see the time at all though, given that you'll have reset it to midnight...

Comment: Jon, so anyway does 12:00:00 in mycase mean that time part is resetted?

Comment: @sergionni: Yes, it's showing that you've set it to midnight. If you change your `c.set` calls to use different values, you'll see the appropriate values in your formatted version too.

Comment: @Jon: i just got real init script fro this table and this field looks like:a_date DATE "MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS" NULLIF (a_date="NULL").

Comment: @serionni: We have no idea what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to say.

Comment: @Jon: sorry, it's SQL loader content, and init script is ok, see please, update in my post

Comment: @sergionni: We *still* don't know what you're trying to achieve, or where the Java part comes in. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @sergionni: But not usefully. Did you read the article I linked to? Have you tried reading your question from the point of view of someone who doesn't know anything *except* what's in your question?

Comment: @Jon: updated once more,problem is narrowed.hope,this description is more clear

Comment: @sergionni: I suspect it's just the *display* format of the data, rather than anything else.

Comment: @Jon:i just installed TOAD on my PC and it displays it with time prefix,but Oracle SQL Developer didn't. Seems,that you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you extend one of the Calendar classes like this:

```
public class CalendarDateOnly extends GregorianCalendar {

    public static Calendar getInstance() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,      cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,      cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        return cal;
    }
}
```

Instantiate in this way:

```
Calendar june30 = CalendarDateOnly.getInstance();
june30.set(2000, Calendar.JUNE, 30);
```

Comment: `extends GregorianCalendar` appears to do nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Date : 2015-07-09
 * Author : Bhuwan Prasad Upadhyay
 */
package com.developerbhuwan.date.utils;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author developerbhuwan
 */
public class CalenderUtils {

    public static Calendar getNewCalendarInstance() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return resetCalender(calendar);
    }

    public static Date resetDate(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return resetCalender(calendar).getTime();
    }

    public static Calendar resetCalender(Calendar calendar) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return calendar;
    }

    public static void setTimeInCalendar(Calendar calendar, Date date) {
        calendar.setTime(resetDate(date));
    }

}
```